# Why can't I create a Jenkins account?

Tags: jenkins

I am new for CI servers. I successfully installed Jenkins on top of Tomcat server. At the initial security configuration, I forgot to check the box for "Allow sign up for new users". Now I can't create an account or it does not allow me to log in as I don't have an account. I tried several things to configure security, but I can't go to that page. Can someone please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've locked yourself out? Being able to sign-up is not going to help you when you locked yourself out, as you would still be missing permissions.

To fix this, you need access to Jenkins installation. Instructions are here:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security

- Stop Jenkins (the easiest way to do this is to kill the servlet container.)
- Go to `$JENKINS_HOME` in the file system and find `config.xml` file.
- Open this file in the editor.
- Look for the `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` element in this file.
- Replace `true` with `false`
- Remove the elements `authorizationStrategy` and `securityRealm`
- Start Jenkins